# Database schema to store configurable sections of a web page

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

It is not a normal CMS feature where I want to store whole page content in one column in the database.

My ASP.NET MVC project requirement is that users selects a web page template to create a web page. 
Template should then be loaded with its relevant sections e.g. Title, Headline, Latest News section having a heading and Text lines, Other Links section containing Links e.g. About Us, Images section containing images, caption etc.
Template has already filled in the sample data into all sections.

All the Page sections and sections' content are configurable. e.g. User choose to add News section. A form will appear having three fields. Title, Text1, Text2 and a button e.g. Add more text. User can then select to add more text or edit text1, text2.

Web Page's main struture is that:

User creates a web page. This page has sections. Sections have links, headline, text, images, video, buttons etc. All sections and their content are configurable.

I am wondering how can this kind of data/configuration be stored in the database. e.g. sql server.

Anyone can please help?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a page associated with a template and has a set of named 'sections'

```
template:
- tid (pk)
- template (blob)

page:
- pid (pk)
- tid (fk to template.tid)
- url (string)

section: (pk=pid + name)
- pid (fk to page.pid)
- name (string)
- content (blob)
```

Comment: Thxnk, I have updated my question. The answer you gave does not fit to my requirements.